# popping ViewController with swipe only works once

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, swipe

If you implement the popViewController:animated: method like this:

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    return [super popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

on a navigation controller, the swipe back gesture only works one time. On the next swipe it won't do anything. Additionally, if you hit the back button then, the view controller will be popped with an animation.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Feel free to try this for yourself: https://github.com/mrmoneyboy/UINavigationController-Tests

Comment: Shouldn't you call `super` with `animated` instead of `NO`?

Comment: Not if I dont want no animation. I only want the swipe to work, which os not the case when implementing the above method.

Comment: Well, still you are breaking things with this. Have you tried looking into `UINavigationControllerDelegate`'s `navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:` for customizing pop transition animation?

Comment: Well obviously I am breaking things with this. But I can't find anything in the docs permitting to override this method and prevent any navigation controller animation.

Comment: Because you are not supposed to do it :) You probably wanna check the aforementioned delegate method and `<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>`, it's there for transition animation customization means.

Comment: Ok Nicky, I think I got it. Might be better if I check the delegate's method you mentioned. Thank you :)